# Error when trying to wait on semaphore

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a class which contains a semaphore. On execution of the classes run method. It creates a thread and passes a function and an object pointer of my class. The function then tried to access the object and the semaphore inside of it and call wait. But the compiler is not letting me do it.

Error:

```
myNode.cpp: In function 'void* MyProjectGraph::compute(void*)':
myNode.cpp:70: error: request for member 'sem' in 'node->MyProjectGraph::MyNode::in.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*, _Alloc = std::allocator<MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*>](((long unsigned int)i))', which is of non-class type 'MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*'
myNode.cpp:82: error: request for member 'sem' in 'node->MyProjectGraph::MyNode::in.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*, _Alloc = std::allocator<MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*>](((long unsigned int)i))', which is of non-class type 'MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*'
myNode.cpp:87: error: request for member 'sem' in 'node->MyProjectGraph::MyNode::out.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*, _Alloc = std::allocator<MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*>](((long unsigned int)i))', which is of non-class type 'MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*'
make: *** [myNode.o] Error 1
```

Method passed in on pthread_create

```
void *compute(void *ptr){
        MyNode* node = (MyNode*)ptr; 
        time_t end;

        cout<<"Node Running: "<<node->ltr<<endl;

        //wait on all incoming edges
        for(int i = 0; i < node->in.size();i++){
            sem_wait(&(node->in[i].sem));   
            //node->in[i].edgeWait();   
        }

        sleep(node->time);
        sem_wait(&count_sem);
        graphCount += node->value;
        sem_post(&count_sem);
        time(&end);

        //destory dependent semaphores
        for(int i = 0; i < node->in.size();i++){
            sem_destroy(&(node->in[i].sem));        
        }

        //post all outgoing edges
        for(int i = 0; i < node->out.size();i++){
            sem_post(&(node->out[i].sem));  
            //node->out[i].edgePost();          
        }

        printf("Node %c computed a value of %d after %.2lf second.",node->ltr,node->value,difftime(end,start)); 
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return 0;
    }
```

Basic design of node and edge classes

```
class MyNode{
        public: 
            int tid;
            int value;
            int time;
            char ltr;

            pthread_t thread;

            std::vector<MyEdge*> in;
            std::vector<MyEdge*> out;

            MyNode( );
            MyNode(char ltr, int val, int time);
            void addInEdge(MyEdge* edge); 
            void addOutEdge(MyEdge* edge); 
            void run( );
            void signalEdges( );
            void waitEdges( ); //Implementation is not known atm
            void toString( );
    };

 class MyEdge{
        public:
            MyNode* in;
            MyNode* out;

            sem_t sem;

            MyEdge(int init, MyNode* in, MyNode* out);
            int edgeWait( );
            int edgePost( );    
    };
}
```

Comment: any tips and recommendations would be appreciated.. I'm trying to learn c++, while doing this assignment, so my code might look odd to you.

Comment: Rather use c++ standard synchronization mechanisms like a [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ use of semaphores in mandatory in this assignment :\

Comment: This has nothing to do with semaphores. Where is your [MCVE]? You should have spent your own time narrowing down the problem.

Comment: The error messages tell you the problem.  `node->in[i]` and `node->out[i]` will return a `MyEdge*` but your dereferencing of `sem` is looking for a reference.  Maybe it will be more clear to you if you wrote: `MyEdge* myEdgePtr = node->in[i]; sem_t* sem = &( myEdgePtr->sem );`  Do you see why I used `->` where you used `.` in `&(node->in[i].sem)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  sem_wait(&(node->in[i].sem));
```

Your `in` class member is a:

```
  std::vector<MyEdge*> in;
```

Therefore, `in[i]` is a `MyEdge *`.

As such, to access its `sem` member, this should be:

```
  sem_wait(&(node->in[i]->sem));
```

The other compilation errors is the same problem.

Comment: @John Well, we all will get what we deserve regarding our actions :) (says a confessing Buddhist)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You mean you're destined to be unfairly dupehammered to death, with the wrong duplicate question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's a thing that can be fixed easily by other dupehammer holders or the community consensus. I don't really think it will affect my _karma_ ;).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes I know that because I have to keep fixing it after you all the time :(

Comment: @Lightness I'll try to improve. Promised! (seems I'm extrapolating too much sometimes, also following _@Queen_'s proposals without closer inspection)

Comment: @Lightness [This kinda stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776437/c-stdcout-as-template-argument) will help to balance my karma anyways.

Comment: My only heroic conquest, to date, is the conquest of compiler error messages. "error: request for member 'sem' ...which is of non-class type 'MyProjectGraph::MyEdge*'". The compiler is looking for a member. I can visualize the compiler's code: ok, I have a member operator here, a ".". But my parse tree type is something other than a class. I'll just complain about a "non-class", and, to be nice, pretty-print the type that's in the parse tree. The rest is history.