# C++ : &(std::cout) as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, cout

Why isn't it possible to pass `std::cout`'s address as template argument?
Or if it is possible then how?

Here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

template<std::ostream* stream>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void disp(void)
        { (*stream) << "hello"; }
};

int main(void)
{
    MyClass<&(std::cout)> MyObj;
    MyObj.disp();

    return 0;
}
```

And the error message I got from `clang++ -std=c++11` :

```
main.cpp:15:11: error: non-type template argument does not refer to any declaration
        MyClass<&(std::cout)> MyObj;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:24: note: template parameter is declared here
template<std::ostream* stream>
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

and from `g++ -std=c++11` :

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:22: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  MyClass<&(std::cout)> MyObj;
                      ^
main.cpp:15:29: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
  MyClass<&(std::cout)> MyObj;
                             ^
main.cpp:16:8: error: request for member ‘disp’ in ‘MyObj’, which is of     non-class type ‘int’
  MyObj.disp();
        ^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you parenthesize it? Also fix the access level.

Comment: Try it without the parentheses: `MyClass<&std::cout> MyObj;`

Comment: I'd like to see an explanation on how this is parsed, though.

Comment: Indeed: it works without the parenthesis! But Why? I tend to put parenthesis quite often especially in cases like `&object.subobject` where it doesn't seem clear to me whether the ampersand is going to apply to `object` or to `subobject` (although I'm sure the standard must lift that ambiguity)… I do agree however that there was no such ambiguity in the present case…

Comment: @GLorieul: `()` makes it an expression that requires runtime evaluation (more or less). Just throwing `()` everywhere without understanding what it does is a bad idea!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh oh, now I see… Would you have a link to a reference that explains that in more detail ?

Comment: I don't think that's a dup.  The Standard has language explicitly saying `&X::m` is required for pointers to member, but I can't find anything that applies here.

Comment: @aschepler I at least think these Q&A are very closely related. The dup contains a standard cite however. Vote to reopen if you think this questin needs to be kept standalone.

Comment: Following @πάντα ῥεῖ 's link, I found a [nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7138582/3492512)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixes your code, omit the parenthesis:

```
#include <iostream>

template<std::ostream* stream>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void disp(void) { 
        (*stream) << "hello"; 
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    MyClass<&std::cout> MyObj;
    MyObj.disp();

    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a05d49a9f9c29942)

---

A more detailed explanation why can be found here:

[Error with address of parenthesized member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134197/error-with-address-of-parenthesized-member-function)

Comment: Thanks for the link! ;)

Comment: @GLorieul Note that `&std::cout` isn't a function pointer at all, but the address of a global instance.

Comment: The "explanation" is bogus. We are not forming a pointer to member here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes indeed `std::cout` is an instance of class `std::ostream` accessible globally (i.e. [declared as](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) `extern std::ostream std::cout`). Yet the same problem as for member functions arise here (as I assume you suggested)

Answer (score 5):

Before C++17 removed this restriction, the syntactic form of a template argument for a pointer or reference template parameter was restricted. N4140 [temp.arg.nontype]/1.3 says that it must be

> expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `&` *id-expression*, where
>   the *id-expression* is the name of an object or function, except that
>   the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and
>   shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a
>   reference

`(std::cout)` isn't an *id-expression*. It's a *primary-expression*.

The "(ignoring parentheses)" part was added by [Core issue 773](http://wg21.link/cwg773), and is apparently meant to permit `(&i)`, not `&(i)`.

Comment: This is a bit too technical for me… What is a "syntatic form"?