# Do parentheses make a pointer template argument invalid?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider this code:

```
int x = 0;

template<int& I>
struct SR {};

template<int* I>
struct SP {};

SR<(x)> sr;
SP<&(x)> sp;

int main(void)
{
}
```

clang++ 3.8.0 complains:

```
main.cpp:10:5: error: non-type template argument does not refer to any declaration
SP<&(x)> sp;
    ^~~
main.cpp:6:15: note: template parameter is declared here
template<int* I>
              ^
```

g++ 6.1.0 complains:

```
main.cpp:10:8: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 SP<&(x)> sp;
        ^
```

Naturally, everything works fine if I remove the parentheses, as in `SP<&x> sp;`.  But I can't find anything in the C++14 Standard that would make a difference here.  Further, why is the reference case okay but the pointer case bad?  Are the compilers correct to reject the program?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This one : [&(std::cout)-as-template-argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776437/c-stdcout-as-template-argument)

Comment: Sorry, yeah. I figured a new more straightforward question about the why was in order, since the answer to the how in the old question was just "remove the parentheses".

Comment: I'm guessing that this has to do with the fact that adding parentheses around the name of an object makes the expression yield an rvalue rather than an lvalue.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure the answer there answers the question. It links to a question specifically about pointers to members, but `std::cout` is an object.

Comment: @templatetypedef If it were that simple, you couldn't do `int f(int&); int x; int y = f((x));`

Comment: @Barry: Not saying it does

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"That's the devil!"_ Well, that leaves me appearing in a bad light. Maybe I should remove my answer (the dupe vote was removed already, although the OP stated it helped them).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: In this context, my phrase just means "That's the one!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My reading of the standard is that it should be allowed, but I suppose the implementors of GCC and Clang disagree with my interpretation, and they're probably correct. For a definitive answer, it might be a good idea to ask the std-discussion@isocpp.org mailing list (I'll shoot them an email). The wording might be a defect.

According to [temp.arg.nontype], one of the possible forms for a non-type template argument is:

> ... a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function
>   templates and function *template-ids* but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `&`*id-expression,* where the *id-expression* is the name of an object or function, except that the
>   `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding
>   *template-parameter* is a reference ...

It all hinges on what "ignoring parentheses" means. GCC and Clang both accept `(&x)` but not `&(x)`; they seem to have decided that "ignoring parentheses" means only on the outside, not around the *id-expression.* If this was the intent of the standards committee, the language should be clarified.

**Edit:** In the [C++17 draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype), this is unambiguously allowed, since the form of allowable non-type template arguments has been relaxed considerably:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of the type of the *template-parameter.* For a non-type *template-parameter* of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject ([intro.object]),
> - a temporary object ([class.temporary]),
> - a string literal ([lex.string]),
> - the result of a `typeid` expression ([expr.typeid]), or
> - a predefined `__func__` variable ([dcl.fct.def.general]).

Comment: Hmm. Is N4296 not close to C++14?  In N4296, [temp.arg.nontype] basically just defers to "converted constant expression" with a few restrictions.

Comment: @aschepler I think N4296 is one of the post-C++14 working drafts. Also see the edits to my answer: I think the wording you're seeing is in C++17.